# MQTT embedded mosca without any broker

Tags: node.js, mqtt, mosca

I would like to use node.js mosca MQTT broker in an embedded way.

From the documentation, it seems that embedded mosca has to use an external broker such as Mosquitto, AMQP, ZeroMQ, Redis. In the case of stand-alone mosca, no external broker is required. Can an embedded mosca be run such that no external broker is used similar to stand-alone mosca?

If this can be done, how should the code that uses redis below be modified?

```
var mosca = require('mosca')

var ascoltatore = {
  type: 'redis',
  redis: require('redis'),
  db: 12,
  port: 6379,
  return_buffers: true, // to handle binary payloads
  host: "localhost"
};

var moscaSettings = {
  port: 1883,
  backend: ascoltatore,
  persistence: {
    factory: mosca.persistence.Redis
  }
};

var server = new mosca.Server(moscaSettings);
server.on('ready', setup);

server.on('clientConnected', function(client) {
    console.log('client connected', client.id);     
});

// fired when a message is received
server.on('published', function(packet, client) {
  console.log('Published', packet.payload);
});

// fired when the mqtt server is ready
function setup() {
  console.log('Mosca server is up and running')
}
```

Comment: This sentence **Can an embedded mosca be run such that no external broker..** doesn't make any sense. **The mosca is the broker**

Answer (score 3):

Here is the full source code of a working example of a secure MQTT broker using mosca run in an embedded way.

```
var mosca = require('mosca')

var SECURE_KEY = __dirname + '/key.pem';
var SECURE_CERT = __dirname + '/cert.pem';

var settings = {
    port: 1883,
    logger: {
        name: "secureSample",
        level: 40,
    },
    secure : {
        port: 7998,
        keyPath: SECURE_KEY,
        certPath: SECURE_CERT,
    }
};
var server = new mosca.Server(settings);
server.on('ready', setup);

server.on('clientConnected', function(client) {
    console.log('client connected', client.id);
});

// fired when a message is received
server.on('published', function(packet, client) {
    console.log('Published', packet.payload);
});

// fired when the mqtt broker is ready
function setup() {
    console.log('Mosca embedded MQTT broker running now')
}
```

Comment: If you are getting Error: error: 0907B068:PEM routines:PEM_READ_BIO_PRIVATEKEY:bad password read https://github.com/mcollina/mosca/issues/421

Answer (score 1):

Mosca is a node.js **mqtt broker**, which can be used:

- Standalone
- Embedded in another Node.js application

and in terms of scalability, their documents state that

> Even though Mosca is a MQTT broker, if you need to scale it out, you need to use another broker as it does not have any clustering support in itself. Some of the brokers it supports are the following:
>
> - Redis, a key/value store created by @antirez.
> - MongoDB, a scalable, high-performance, document-oriented database.
> - Mosquitto and all implementations of the MQTT protocol.
> - RabbitMQ and all implementations of the AMQP protocol.
> - ZeroMQ to use Mosca in a P2P fashion.

[here](http://github.com/mcollina/mosca/wiki#does-it-scale)  is their wiki